# I want to connect via SSH from Windows Machine to Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, windows

I want to create a SSH tunnel but I dont know how to identify my Windows 7 machine.

In the command below, what do I have to put replace `me@win7_machine` with in order for it to work? Is it my `username@IP_address`? `username@pcname`?

```
 ssh -R 12345:localhost:3306 me@win7_machine -N
```

Comment: Your command looks like you want to connect **to** a Windows machine, **not from**!?

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to ssh to your windows box you need a running ssh server on the windows box, and the ip address.

- winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server
- www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-learn-your-computer-s-ip-address-windows-7-windows-8

also please read:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding